# aJax post back not calling controller in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a drop down list that on change I fire a aJax call with this code

the code hits the controller as if i remove it the ajax errors but I am unable to see why its not passing anything back

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#lid").on("change", function () {

        var myVar = $(this).find("option:selected").text()

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("UpdateLang")",
            type: "POST",
            data: { model: JSON.stringify(myVar) },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error"); // response.responseText
        },
            success: function (response) {
                alert("set to " + myVar);
        }
    });
    })

});
```

and the I have the next code in my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateLang(loggedinViewModel model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            return Json("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("An Error Has occoured");
        }

    }
```

I have no idea but why, but the aJax call is not fireing my controller

any reason why any help please ?

Comment: What controller is you actionResult on?

Comment: its on the accountcontroller.cs

Comment: and your JS is where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you having this issue because of rights to the controller c#, trying calling the Action Result from 'homecontoller.cs' or something, plus your not actually passing an array of data back for the model so this will also fail

hope this is some guidance